# Adding another class row to an object array

Tags: php

I have the following array inside an object (from var_dump)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (1) {
    ["jquery"]=>
    string(64) "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (1) {
    ["bootstrap"]=>
    string(67) "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  }
}
```

I want to be able to add another 'row' on to that.  How can I do that?  So I'm aiming for something like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (1) {
    ["jquery"]=>
    string(64) "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (1) {
    ["bootstrap"]=>
    string(67) "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (1) {
    ["another"]=>
    string(67) "https://anothercdn//"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your variable looks like this JSON: `[{"jquery": "https://"},{"bootstrap":"..."}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array_push() for this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

or simply add [] after array, like $myArray[] = $newObject

Answer (score 2):

If you array is in a variable called `$myArray`, then you can do the following ...

```
$myArray[] = (object) [
  'another' => "https://anothercdn//"
];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$assets1` as the array of assets 1 and 2 as the second

```
foreach($assets2 as $asset2)
{
  array_push($assets1, $asset2);
}

print_r($assets1);
```